# improve pandas and dask aggregate custom function speed

Tags: python, pandas, cython, numba

For pandas/dask aggregate, using the built in function. It is indeed very fast. For example, my initial aggregate function works very efficiently. This aggregate function works very smooth

```
{"volume":["sum"],"high":["max"],"low":["min"]}
```

However, I also need the first and last aggregate

```
def first(rows):
    return rows[0]
def last(rows):
    return rows[-1]

{"volume":["sum"],"open":[first],"close":[last],"high":["max"],"low":["min"]}
```

Such aggregate becomes 100 times slower... Is it possible to use some tricks to improve its performance? Like using cypthon, numba etc.?

**Edit**: ok, so pandas has such aggregate function, I'm actually running it in dask with this line:

```
        final_df_tmp =  df_tx_counts_input.map_overlap(
            lambda x: x.groupby(id_col_name)[data_cols_tmp].rolling(f"{rolling_window_now}ns").agg(agg_operations).sort_index(level=1), 
            pd.Timedelta(f"{rolling_window_now}ns"), 
            0)#.reset_index()
```

If I used the custom built in :

```
    grand_agg_instruction[rolling_window_now]={"volume":["sum"],"open":["first"],"close":["last"],"high":["max"],"low":["min"]}
```

Error says:

```
AttributeError("'first' is not a valid function for 'RollingGroupby' object")
```

Answer (score 1):

We have build in function

```
d = {"volume":["sum"],"open":['first'],"close":['last'],"high":["max"],"low":["min"]}
```

Comment: hi Thanks so much for your answer, I updated my question... I am actually using dask to implement it... Is it possible to call pandas internal function to accelerate my groupby rolling aggregate?